# Why is my private constructor public when checked with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, private-constructor

I have (among many other Util classes which do not have this problem) a class FileUtil which fails the test for having a private constructor.

The class definition is:

```
public final class FileUtil {

    /**
     * Hidden constructor to prevent instantiation.
     */
    private FileUtil() {
    }
    // ...
    // many static methods
}
```

As mentioned above I have many other classes which are tested for having private constructors. The test method is:

```
@Test
public void testPrivateConstructor() throws Exception {
    Constructor<FileUtil> constructor = FileUtil.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
    Assert.assertTrue("Constructor is not private", Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    constructor.newInstance();
}
```

But for this class - and only for this class - the isPrivate() method returns false and if checking in the debugger the constructor indeed is shown as public. However, if trying to call the constructor programmatically, Eclipse tells me the method is not visible.

I'm working with Eclipse and Maven and the problem shows in Eclipse and also on the command line when calling the Maven build. So it's really a Java problem, but as I use this pattern throughout my library without problems I do not see why it fails with this class only.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Since `FileUtil` is such a common name, maybe you are using different `FileUtil` class. In any case the above code, as it is, should not give you `false` for `isPrivate`.

Comment: Did you make a [mcve] to test this in isolation? I did and it works just fine, so the suggestion by @tsolakp and @DwB is almost certain to be correct... you are looking at a different `FileUtil`.  For stuff like this, ALWAYS make a [mcve] before posting.  If you don't find the problem yourself, then when you post you have something everybody can quickly reproduce and verify.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks for pointing this out. I found the solution below when creating the example ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First guess; these are not the FileUtil you're looking for.

Print out `FileUtil.class.getName()`.
For example:

```
System.out.println("FileUtil classname: " + FileUtil.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. However, the problem was caused by something completely different:

In some other test I had to mock some methods of this class. Since all the methods are static I had to use

```
@PrepareForTest(FileUtil.class)
```

on the unit-test class. I suppose this was the reason I got a mock-object with public constructor in the testPrivateConstructor() method.

I refactored all the tests which need mocking into a separate test class, and removed the @PrepareForTest(FileUtil.class) from the test class which contains the testPrivateConstructor() method. Now it works as expected.

Hope this helps if someone runs into the same problem again.